# How to convert lists in Python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, replace

I a have a list generated from some input eg:

```
text = input("Please enter the text you would like to encrypt: ")
textlist = text.split
```

If I want to convert all the A's in the list to B's, how can I do this?

**Eg Input:** Hello my name is ana

**Output:** Hello my nbme is bnb

Comment: `'Hello my name is ana Output'.replace('a','b').replace('A','B')` or use `str.translate`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723751/replacing-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New to Python, replacing characters in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810449/new-to-python-replacing-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

`text.split` just returns an instance of a built-in python method.

```
>>> text.split
<built-in method split of str object at 0x10c0b36c0>
```

If you want to *use* the split method, you need to do `text.split()` (with the parentheses). in any case, this method does not do what you are looking for - it will return a list with one element:

```
>>> text.split()
['hello my name is ana']
```

To convert the string to a list of characters, use `list(text)`:

```
>>> list(text)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'a']
```

However, in any case, simply replacing characters in the string is much easier than that, and should not require converting the string to a list.

```
>>> text.replace('a', 'b')
'hello my nbme is bnb'
```